# Entity Framework wrapper for querying multiple identical DbContexts (shards)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, sharding

I'm trying to implement sharding for our database and I'm having trouble with using Entity Framework to query multiple shards at the same time so we can get a full list of entities.
I was hoping to make a class similar to a context that can expose `IQueryable<T>` for each of my `DbSet<T>`, capture the queries made and run them against each shard, and aggregate the results before returning them. Ideally this should be as easy to use as:

```
using (AllShardContext db = new AllShardContext())
{
    List<Item> items = db.Items.Where(it => it.Price > 100).ToList()
}
```

I've been trying to make a custom `IQueryProvider` and `IQueryable` and have captured the `Expression` run against the `IQueryable` but cannot get this to run against an actual EF context.
I'm getting `The specified cast from a materialized 'Testing.Item' type to the 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery1[Testing.Item]' type is not valid.`

Am I on the right track? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you looked at Entity Framework Elastic Scale? I wouldn't fancy implementing sharding myself. http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-scale-get-started/

Comment: Unfortunately we're not on Azure, else we'd happily be using it. At this point, moving platform to Azure isn't feasible.